# I have a trouble in setting up gmaps.js in my google ap

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i have some trouble in implementing this multiple input pin in google map
THE ERROR "cannot call method 'setContextMenu' is undefined
does anyone know how i am going to fixed it

```
    var map;
    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.2833, 123.9000)
      };


      map.setContextMenu({ 
      control: 'map',
      options: [{
        title: 'Add marker',
        name: 'add_marker',
        action: function(e) {
          this.addMarker({
            lat: e.latLng.lat(),
            lng: e.latLng.lng(),
            title: 'New marker'
          });
        }
      }, {
        title: 'Center here',
        name: 'center_here',
        action: function(e) {
          this.setCenter(e.latLng.lat(), e.latLng.lng());
        }
      }]
    });

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize `map` before using it. move this call down `map.setContextMenu` below the line that you initialize the map `map = new google.maps.Map(`

```
//first initialize the map
map = new google.maps.Map( //...

//now it is safe to use
map.setContextMenu({
```